# Behaviour of dfmax in glmnet

Tags: r, glmnet

(NB: This is a slightly modified version of a post I'd made on a different forum. I received no responses there, hence the post here. If this is not allowed, please let me know, will take down the question).

I am new to *glmnet*, so I do not yet understand fully what the various 
parameters do. I am trying to build a multinomial classifier which restricts 
the number of features used in the model. From reading the docs and some 
answers on this forum, I understand `dfmax` is the way to do it. I 
played around with it a bit; I have a couple of questions and would appreciate some help:

#### Setup

For a particular dataset, I want to restrict the number of features to 3; 
the original data has 126 features. Here's what I run:

```
fit<-glmnet(data.matrix(X), data.matrix(y), family='multinomial', dfmax=3) 
d<-data.frame(tidy(fit))
```

This is the value of `d`:

[image]

My questions about the output:

1. I see multiple values of `lambda` in there; it looks like
   glmnet tries to fit `lambda`s that gets the number of terms close to
   `dfmax=3`. So its less like the LARs algorithm (where we
   move stagewise by adding variables and can stop at an exact number of variables) and more about getting the
   right `lambda`s for regularization that lead to the intended `dfmax`. Is
   this right?
2. I'm guessing `alpha` plays a role in how close we can get
   to `dfmax`. At `alpha=1`, where we're doing lasso, and so its easier to
   get close to `dfmax`, compared to when `alpha=0` and we're doing ridge.
   Is this understanding correct?
3. A "neighborhood" of `dfmax` is the
   best we can do it'd seem. Or am I missing a parameter that gets me
   to the model with the exact `dfmax` (FYI: `alpha=1` doesn't seem to get
   me to the precise number of non zero terms either, at least on this
   dataset).
4. In the first solution - `step=1`, there are no variables used. Does this mean the relative odds equal a constant?
5. What does `pmax` do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I too am just starting with `glmnet` but, about your last question, I found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114128/glmnet-in-r-difference-between-dfmax-and-pmax). Also, you have read some docs but [this link](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmnet/versions/2.0-16/topics/glmnet), if you missed it, may be helpful (it's about the R version but that won't be much of a problem for you if you're using the Python version).

Comment: Also, scroll down in [this](https://github.com/civisanalytics/python-glmnet/blob/master/glmnet/doc.py) about half way and find the `elnet` call.

Comment: Also, scroll down in [this](https://github.com/civisanalytics/python-glmnet/blob/master/glmnet/doc.py) about half way and find the `elnet` call. There `ne` corresponds to `dfmax` and `nx` is `pmax`. Evidently "model" means a particular choice of `lambda` and `param` is `alpha`. And `n_features` is the number of independent variables. And "largest model (stopping
    criterion)" evidently refers to the minimum mean-square-error `lambda` (or thereabouts)--- the number of non-zero betas increases as `lambda` is decreased.

Comment: @MikeO'Connor I am seeing this after ages, but thank you! Very helpful comments! In short: if I want to fix the number of non-zero terms for classification, I need only use `pmax` (in the `glmnet` package). What I discovered is that sometimes the algorithm stops *before* it reaches the prescribed `pmax` - because of the default `lambda` step-size (the algorithm is supposed to stop before it *exceeds* the supplied `pmax`). In these cases, decreasing the step-size often works to get to the precise `pmax`: by using a higher number for `nlambda` (default is `100`).

Comment: It's indeed been a while. I'm still very actively using `glmnet` but I gave up on trying to rely on `pmax`. I simply screen all of the outcomes for all of the hyperparameters and do "validation" only with the combinations that yield a number of features that is within my target range.

Comment: I see. I used to do that earlier but the problem is if I needed to run many evaluations quickly (several thousands right one after another) this was slow, because the whole path would be explored, much of which I didn't require. I will be working on using `pmax` for the next few days to see how it fares. I did some cursory inspection by looking at the `tidy(fit)` object (here `fit` is the return from `glmnet()` and `tidy` comes from the `broom` package), so far no problems (nb: I am using `family=binomial`; with `multinomial` it gets a little messy).

Comment: I have indeed had to resort to `joblib` and parallel processing to speed things up a bit.